# Parse JSONArray inside JSONArray

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am using [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) for parsing json response. I need to parse JSONArry inside JsonArray..

My response is..

```
{
"message": "Retreive sucessfully",
"flag": true,
"data": {
    "myArray1": [[{
        "xyz": "1400.0",
        "abc": "O",
        "mnp": "leeper"
    },
    {
        "xyz": "1400.0",
        "abc": "J",
        "mnp": "leeper"
    },
    {
        "xyz": "1400.0",
        "abc": "I",
        "mnp": "leeper"
    },
    {
        "xyz": "1400.0",
        "abc": "D",
        "mnp": "leeper"
    },
    {
        "xyz": "1400.0",
        "abc": "C",
        "mnp": "leeper"
    }],
    [{
        "xyz": "1400.0",
        "abc": "M",
        "mnp": "leeper"
    },
    {
        "xyz": "1400.0",
        "abc": "L",
        "mnp": "leeper"
    },
    {
        "xyz": "1400.0",
        "abc": "G",
        "mnp": "leeper"
    },
    {
        "xyz": "1400.0",
        "abc": "F",
        "mnp": "leeper"
    },
    {
        "xyz": "1400.0",
        "abc": "A",
        "mnp": "leeper"
    }]],
    "myArray2": [[{
        "xyz": "1000.0",
        "abc": "notaes",
        "mnp": null
    }],
    [{
        "xyz": "1400.0",
        "abc": "LS5",
        "mnp": "leeper"
    },
    {
        "xyz": "1400.0",
        "abc": "LS4",
        "mnp": "leeper"
    },
    {
        "xyz": "1400.0",
        "abc": "LS3",
        "mnp": "leeper"
    },
    {
        "xyz": "1400.0",
        "abc": "LS2",
        "mnp": "leeper"
    },
    {
        "xyz": "1400.0",
        "abc": "LS1",
        "mnp": "leeper"
    }],
    [{
        "xyz": "1000.0",
        "abc": "19",
        "mnp": "taes"
    },
    {
        "xyz": "1000.0",
        "abc": "notaes",
        "mnp": null
    },
    {
        "xyz": "1000.0",
        "abc": "notaes",
        "mnp": null
    },
    {
        "xyz": "1000.0",
        "abc": "notaes",
        "mnp": null
    },
    {
        "xyz": "1000.0",
        "abc": "notaes",
        "mnp": null
    },
    {
        "xyz": "1000.0",
        "abc": "notaes",
        "mnp": null
    },
    {
        "xyz": "1000.0",
        "abc": "notaes",
        "mnp": null
    },
    {
        "xyz": "1000.0",
        "abc": "notaes",
        "mnp": null
    },
    {
        "xyz": "1000.0",
        "abc": "notaes",
        "mnp": null
    },
    {
        "xyz": "1000.0",
        "abc": "notaes",
        "mnp": null
    }],
    [{
        "xyz": "1000.0",
        "abc": "notaes",
        "mnp": null
    },
    {
        "xyz": "1000.0",
        "abc": "notaes",
        "mnp": null
    },
    {
        "xyz": "1000.0",
        "abc": "20",
        "mnp": "taes"
    },
    {
        "xyz": "1000.0",
        "abc": "6",
        "mnp": "taes"
    },
    {
        "xyz": "1000.0",
        "abc": "3",
        "mnp": "taes"
    },
    {
        "xyz": "1000.0",
        "abc": "2",
        "mnp": "taes"
    }],
    [{
        "xyz": "1000.0",
        "abc": "notaes",
        "mnp": null
    },
    {
        "xyz": "1000.0",
        "abc": "1",
        "mnp": "taes"
    }]]
},
"code": "99"
}
```

What should be my class? I have done like this...

```
public class MyLayout {
public String message;
public boolean flag;
public Data data;
public String commandName;
public String code;

public class Data {
    public ArrayList<MyClass> myArray1 = new ArrayList<MyLayout.MyClass>();
    public ArrayList<MyClass> myArray2 = new ArrayList<MyLayout.MyClass>();
}

public class MyClass {
    public String abc;
    public String xyz;
    public String mnp;
}

}
```

It's not working??

**EDIT**

My Above `MyLayout` works when response is like below..But what about `myArray` item also contains `JSONArray`

```
{
"message": "Retreive sucessfully",
"flag": true,
"data": {
"myArray1": [{
    "xyz": "1400.0",
    "abc": "O",
    "mnp": "leeper"
},
{
    "xyz": "1400.0",
    "abc": "J",
    "mnp": "leeper"
},
{
    "xyz": "1400.0",
    "abc": "I",
    "mnp": "leeper"
},
{
    "xyz": "1400.0",
    "abc": "D",
    "mnp": "leeper"
},
{
    "xyz": "1400.0",
    "abc": "C",
    "mnp": "leeper"
}],
"myArray2": [{
    "xyz": "1400.0",
    "abc": "LS5",
    "mnp": "leeper"
},
{
    "xyz": "1400.0",
    "abc": "LS4",
    "mnp": "leeper"
},
{
    "xyz": "1400.0",
    "abc": "LS3",
    "mnp": "leeper"
},
{
    "xyz": "1400.0",
    "abc": "LS2",
    "mnp": "leeper"
},
{
    "xyz": "1400.0",
    "abc": "LS1",
    "mnp": "leeper"
}]
},
"code": "99"
}
```

Comment: what the problem? Your solution not works?

Comment: Yuap.. not working...

Comment: are you opposed to using JSON instead of Gson?

Comment: I am trying to explain `MyClass` is also having `JSONArray`. How to resolve that.

Comment: It's an array inside of an array.  How would you handle it if it were a kumquat inside an array?  You'd index the array to extract the kumquat and then operate on the kumquat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`myArray1` and `myArray2` are arrays of arrays, so you'll need to modify `Data` to look like this:

```
public class Data {
  public List<List<MyClass>> myArray1 = ...
  public List<List<MyClass>> myArray2 = ...
}
```